# Updating sort keys after delete

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table which has a field `sort_id`. In this field there are numbers from 1 to n, that define the order of the data sets.
Now I want to delete some elements and afterwards I want to reorder the table. Therefore I need a query that "finds" the gaps and changes the `sort_id` field according to the modifications.

Sure, I could do something like this:

```
SELECT sort_id FROM table WHERE id = 5
```

Then save the sort_id and afterwards:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 5
UPDATE table SET sort_id = sort_id - 1 WHERE sort_id > {id from above}
```

But I'd like to do the reordering process in one step.

Answer (score 3):

Mladen and Arvo have good ideas, but unfortunately in MySQL you can't `SELECT` and `UPDATE` the same table in the same statement (even in a subquery).  This is a known limitation of MySQL.

Here's a solution that uses MySQL user variables:

```
SET @i := 0;
UPDATE mytable
SET sort_id = (@i := @i + 1)
ORDER BY sort_id;
```

For what it's worth, I wouldn't bother doing this anyway.  If your `sort_id` is used only for sorting and not as a kind of "row number," then the rows are still in sorted order after you delete the row where `id=6`.  The values don't necessarily have to be consecutive for sorting.

Comment: They don't have to be consecutive for sorting, true, but leaving the hole could make some code that is expecting to be able to swap or increment / decrement behave unexpectedly. As you say may or may not matter. +1 for the MySQL-specific solution.

Comment: Brilliant and efficient, thanks Bill!! Small addition, is that in case you use **PDO** you must pre-run a query to set a variable: `$pdo->query( "SET @i = 0" );`

Answer (score 0):

for sql server 2005:
this is how you get the new sequence:

```
SELECT row_number() over(order by sort_id) as RN
FROM table
```

updating the table means you should join that select to your update:

```
update t1
set sort_id = t2.RN
FROM table t1 
     join (SELECT row_number() over(order by sort_id) as RN FROM table) t2 
        on t1.UniqueId = t2.UniqueId
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't mentioned that I need standard SQL or at least a MySQL specific query.
Any ideas?

Comment: In MySQL, you can't do UPDATE and SELECT of the same table in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MySQL syntax variations and cannot test query live, but something like next should give you at least an idea:

```
update table t1
set sort_id = (select count * from table t2 where t2.sort_id <= t1.sort_id)
```

Comment: In MySQL, you can't do UPDATE and SELECT of the same table in the same query.